# How to get sub-string in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

My response of an API is like
"details" : "AccNo : 102478955441205"
When i used "Regular Expression Extractor" to store the value in a variable it is successfully stored with the following regex "details"\s:\s*"([^"]*)"
The problem is when I'm trying to use it, the response is coming as AccNo : 1010201213000005 but what i need is just the number. Can someone help me out

## Json Body

{
"statusCode" : "sfewr",
"statusDes" : "Record inserted successfully!!  ",
"statusType" : "X",
"details" : "AccNo : 102478955441205"
}

## Regex used :

"details"\s:\s*"([^"]*)"

## Actual Result

"AccNo : 102478955441205"

## Expected Result:

102478955441205

Comment: It is advisable to parse JSON with the right tool, e.g. [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your regex a bit, so your group1 only matches the digits. You can use this regex,

```
"details"\s:\s*"\D*(\d+)"
```

I've used `\D*` to match any non-digit text and have kept it out of first grouping pattern so your group1 contents are only digits. Also changed `[^"]*` to `\d+` as what you want to get in group1 is only digits. Although, if you want, you can retain `[^"]*` too instead of `\d+`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kfqa7N/1/)**